# CSV to array encoding characters

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a csv from remote, columns inside csv has accented characters, my aim is to convert this csv to associative array like i proceed below :

```
/*------------------------------------
* CONVERT CSV FILE TO ARRAY
* @params $filename
* return array
------------------------------------*/
function csv_to_array($filename = '', $delimiter=';')
{

    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $d = array_map("utf8_encode", $row);
            if(!$header)
                $header = $d;
            else if( count($header) == count($row) )
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

and the output is :

```
if( file_exists('fic.csv')) $csv_to_array = csv_to_array('fic.csv');
/*------------------------------------
* PRINT OUT CSV
------------------------------------*/
foreach($csv_to_array as $key => $value ){
    $country = $value['country'];
    echo $country;
}
```

And it output country name with non encoded characters :
    Bangkok - P�kin - San Jos�

When inserting to DB those non encoded characters produce a bug, how do i handle them from insertion? an idea please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify encoding for the file. Use [stream_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-encoding.php) function:

```
stream_encoding($handle, "UTF-8"); // or whatever the input is encoded in
```

Comment: `$handle` refers to the variable of the same name from your example, i.e. the stream.